# img src not working correctly in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, images, urls

I am new to wordpress. i have a raw html box in my page having img link

`<button><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/05/video-popup.png" ></button>`

it shows img url as **''mysite/beta/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/video-popup.png"**
when i use same in custom post type it shows a **404 error** with the url link 
**''mysite/beta/dictionary/a/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/video-popup.png"**

dictionary is the post type and 'a' is the page of dictionary type.
kindly help me out of this how to get rid of this issue

Comment: please try to <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>">

Comment: i'm using raw html element of visual composer/wp-bakery plugin. i can''t write php there.

Comment: Why is there a `.` at the beginning of your URL?

Comment: @TomJNowell dot indicates one step back to root than goto wp-content and so on

Comment: `.` means `current directory`, `..` means `parent directory`

Comment: hmmm are you sure those are URL semantics and not file system semantics? `test/example` would be better than `./test/example`, eitherway those are all relative paths which will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this following function to your functions.php of your theme or child theme.

```
function homeURLshortcode()
{
    return home_url();
}
add_shortcode('homeurl', 'homeURLshortcode');
```

This will create a shortcode like `[homeurl]` which you can use to add in any visual editor and it will render as your main domain address, like http://domain.com.

So for your image url you need to add `[homeurl]/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/video-popup.png`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it absolutely solved my problem. @ovidiua2003

Comment: you are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these URLs are all relative URLs that refer to the current URL. That's the URL of the post, not the URL of the site, which means wether it works or not will depend on where on the site you are. As a result the URL needed to make this work changes for each individual page you visit

E.g. on my own site tomjn.com I have the `wp-content` folder at `tomjn.com/wp-content`

If I use `/wp-content` it always refers to `tomjn.com/wp-content`

But, if I use a relative path, it gets appended to the current URL e.g. for `./wp-content` or `wp-content` I get:

- On `tomjn.com` it will try to load `tomjn.com/wp-content`
- On `tomjn.com/wp-admin` it will try to load `tomjn.com/wp-admin/wp-content` which won't work
- On `https://tomjn.com/2018/04/19/leafleting-wordcamps-a-psa/` it will try to load `https://tomjn.com/2018/04/19/leafleting-wordcamps-a-psa/wp-content` which won't work
- On `https://tomjn.com/2018/03/16/utility-taxonomies/` it will try to load `https://tomjn.com/2018/03/16/utility-taxonomies/wp-content` which won't work
- On `https://tomjn.com/articles/` it will try to load `https://tomjn.com/articles/wp-content` which won't work

So the solution is to use absolute paths, or, use paths relative to the root e.g. `/wp-content/uploads`

---

Of course, the real solution is to not hardcode paths at all, and to use attachment IDs and WP APIs to generate the URLs.